# `npm publish` ignoring new additions to .npmignore

Tags: npm, npm-publish, npmignore, npm-pack

While building `create-near-app`, artifacts get created within the project tree. Some of these [were added](https://github.com/near/create-near-app/pull/386/files) to a `.npmignore` file, but others were missed until I attempted to publish a new version and noticed that the npm package would be several hundred megabytes large (!!) due to Rust build artifacts. I [added](https://github.com/near/create-near-app/commit/91b8bddbd4119b56ee519bf95c2006ca4a4ea1fd) these to `.npmignore`, but `npm publish` is failing to notice.

I am able to work around this by removing the files, but such a workaround is error prone for an open source library which may be maintained and published by a growing & morphing team of contributors.

Does npm cache the `.npmignore` file somewhere? How do I make npm use the new settings?

---

Details & quick reference:

os: macOS 10.15.6
node version manager: [asdf](https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf) v0.7.6
node: v12.14.1
npm: v6.13.7

**package.json**:

```
-- snip --
"files": [
  "/common",
  "/templates"
],
-- snip --
```

**.npmignore**:

```
common/contracts/rust/target
common/contracts/out
templates/*/.cache
templates/*/assembly
-- snip --
```

**output of `npm pack --dryrun`**:

```
-- snip --
npm notice 293.2kB common/contracts/rust/target/debug/build/ryu-140fa0ad757694f9/build_script_build-140fa0ad757694f9                                                                           
npm notice 20.6kB  common/contracts/rust/target/debug/build/ryu-140fa0ad757694f9/build_script_build-140fa0ad757694f9.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/build_script_build-140fa0ad757694f9         
npm notice 297.4kB common/contracts/rust/target/debug/build/serde-3bef95b74f70906a/build_script_build-3bef95b74f70906a                                                                         
-- snip --
```

---

If you want to try it yourself:

1. clone the repository
2. `cd common/contracts/rust`
3. `cargo build` (you will need to [install Rust](https://rustup.rs/))
4. `cd ../../..`
5. `npm pack --dryrun`

Does it work for you? Is this an "only broken on my machine" thing?

Comment: So, presumably every pattern currently specified in your [.npmignore](https://github.com/near/create-near-app/blob/master/.npmignore) is _NOT_ being ignored, i.e. they are being included. Is that a correct assumption of what you believe the issue is? Or is it only [these patterns](https://github.com/near/create-near-app/commit/91b8bddbd4119b56ee519bf95c2006ca4a4ea1fd), i.e. the ones where you say _"I added these to .npmignore"_, that are _NOT_ being ignored, whilst all the other patterns are being ignored correctly?

Comment: @RobC only the newly-added patterns are not being picked up correctly, but the ones I added originally are. So in this case, all paths in `templates/*` are ignored, but the paths in `common/contracts` are included in the package.

Answer (score 3):

> *"Is this an "only broken on my machine" thing?"*

No, this is *(almost)* expected behaviour given your projects current configuration(s) - and *no* npm doesn't cache the `.npmignore` file somewhere.

The reason I said *"almost"* previously is because in your last comment you said:

> *"So in this case, all paths in `templates/*` are ignored, but the paths in `common/contracts` are included in the package."*

That should not be the case because according to npm's expected behaviour as stated in the docs, *(see "Why is this happening?" section below)*, none of the patterns currently specified in your *.npmignore* file *should* be effective given your current *package.json*'s `files` configuration.

What you're encountering is *odd* behaviour, i.e. some patterns are being respected whilst others are not, however hopefully by following either of the two proposed solutions/approaches (below) you'll get the correct desired result.

---

#### Why is this happening?

The docs for *package.json*'s [`files`](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#files) field states the following which is pertinent to your issue:

<sub>***Note:** Bold emphasis added by me.*</sub>

> *You can also provide a `.npmignore` file in the root of your package or in subdirectories, which will keep files from being included. **At the root of your package it will not override the “files” field**, but in subdirectories it will.*

So, the reason why the patterns currently specified in your *[.npmignore](https://github.com/near/create-near-app/blob/master/.npmignore)* file are *NOT* being ignored is because they are trying to override the inclusion patterns currently specified in your *package.json*'s `files` field. Essentially, because your *.npmignore* file currently resides ***at the root of your package it will not override the “files" field***.

---

#### Solutions

Here are a two different solutions/methods to consider (they're in no particular order):

1. **Omit the `files` entry from *package.json* and augment your current *.npmignore* file as necessary**

   i.e. Delete this from *package.json*:

   ```
   "files": [
    "/common",
    "/templates"
   ],
   ```

   Then create additional patterns in your current *.npmignore* file for any other directories/files that should also be excluded from packing/publishing. In other words add any patterns to *.npmignore* for assets that do not reside somewhere in `/common` or `/templates` that should also be excluded.

   For example, after briefly looking at your repo, you'll need to add the pattern `tests` to *.npmignore* too.

   In summary, this first approach is a case of delete the `files` field and specify all patterns for assets to be ignored in one place - in the `.npmignore` file at the root of your project.
2. **Or, keep the `files` entry in *package.json* as-is and create additional *.npmignore* files in subdirectories**

   Given the patterns currently specified in your *.npmignore* file are:

   > ```
   > common/contracts/rust/target
   > common/contracts/out
   > templates/*/.cache
   > templates/*/assembly
   > templates/*/contract
   > templates/*/package.json
   > templates/*/src/assets
   > templates/*/src/config.js
   > templates/*/src/global.css
   > templates/*/src/utils.js
   > ```

   and also given that the docs stated; *"at the root of your package [.npmignore] will not override the “files” field, **but in subdirectories it will**"* then you'll need to:

   1. Create a *.npmignore* file in the `common/contracts/` directory containing the following patterns:

      ```
      rust/target
      out
      ```
   2. Create a *.npmignore* file in the `templates/` directory containing the following patterns:

      ```
      */.cache
      */assembly
      */contract
      */package.json
      */src/assets
      */src/config.js
      */src/global.css
      */src/utils.js
      ```

   The `.npmignore` file currently residing at the root of your project directory (as-is) becomes redundant with this second method.

---

**Note:** Hopefully by following either of the two aforementioned solutions/methods, (which do closely adhere to npm's documented expectations), you'll get the desired result. However, if neither of those proposed solutions yield the desired result, then I suggest keeping one of the proposed solutions as a baseline starting point, then reading some of the answers in [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27049192/npm-publish-isnt-including-all-my-files). Yes, the question is the opposite of your issue, however you might gain further insight towards next steps particularly from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27049192/npm-publish-isnt-including-all-my-files#answer-51107553) - it mentions *"npm pack and publish respect any package.json files you have in the directory tree, not just at the root."*.

---

Comment: Thanks, @RobC! Fixed here https://github.com/near/create-near-app/commit/1abf5626e4ac0de57b34ebdbd9de262bbf020bfc – as mentioned there, I was wrong about the `templates/*` rules working correctly. `npm pack` always ignores symlinks, and I've also now verified that `npm pack` uses `.gitignore` from within each subdirectory, which is why the `.cache` folders were being ignored. All of the `templates/*` rules in my original question were superfluous; a red herring.